# Aligning Items Across Different Power Point Pages

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to arrange three slides in my power point presentation..

I am doing screen caps from another app.

I'm pasting those screencaps into three Powepoint slides.

I want the user to see the same sized images on all three slides

I want the user to see the three images in the same position on all three slides

At this moment, I'm close, but they are just enough off so that the viewer is distracted.

I looked at the top 4 closest matches that SuperUser.com suggested as possible duplicate questions, and I didn't see this exact question answered, so thanks for pointing me somewhere else if this is a needless dupe.

Comment: Did you try creating the first slide exactly how you wanted it, duplicating the slide, then changing the image to the desired one?

Comment: Also it helps to turn the grid on for alignment purposes.

Comment: @bobSmith1432, Yes, that's how I got the sizes wrong; pretty close, but still wrong

Comment: @James, Never heard of the grid. How do I turn it on ?

Comment: In office 2007 and 2010 it is on the View tab under the show section.

Comment: @James, you are the hero.  It's under `View` and one of the twenty one different things displayed on that menu is `Gridlines` just above `Show/Hide`  Thank you; this should help a lot; plus one and thanks; I'm back to work !

Comment: The screen captures have to be exact.  What I've done in the past is to capture the first screen and open it up in Paint.net or any graphics program with layer capability.  I then add the send screen capture to a layer in Paint.net and manually match the two slides up.  Most of my work has a transparent background.  I then save the two layers separately.  In PPT, I get the first slide exactly how I want it and the copy that slide down.  I the change the picture to the next inline.  Works beautifully.